# Subset Data in R excluding 13

Tags: r, subset

```
Date    Check
201006  1649.515
201007  1825.828
201008  1878.926
201009  1637.491
201010  1664.938
201011  1973.294
201012  2714.054
201013  24086.797
201101  2888.64
201102  2452.403
201103  2230.493
201104  1825.023
201105  1667.396
201106  1657.334
201107  1890.515
201108  1891.783
201109  1655.634
201110  1744.454
201111  2031.872
201112  2541.878
201113  24477.425
```

I have a dataset. All data is monthly. How to subset the data so that 201113 and 201013 are excluded?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the `13` mentioned is specific to the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!grepl("13",Date))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
 df[!df$Date %in% c(201113, 201013),]
```

Or if `13` should be excluded

```
 subset(df, !substr(Date, nchar(Date)-1, nchar(Date))==13)
```

Or

```
 subset(df, !is.na(as.Date(paste0(Date, '01'), '%Y%m%d')) )
```